# position on Map then i want to give certain details on the city he lives in

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, maps

I need a direction, 'cause I don't know how to look for it, or basically how to do that.
Every time a user presses a locate button it will locate his position (already done this part)
And then, I want to give certain details about his city (in my case, I want to give corona details of people amount that are infected in the city area)
**for example**: so lets say the user lives in new york, and then he clicks on locate position, it gives him the amount of sick people in his area.
i used this website for my code:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_locate.html
my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>OpenStreetMap</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.35/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #esri-map-container {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
      }
      #LocateButton {
      position: absolute;
      top: 95px;
      left: 20px;
      z-index: 50;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.35/"></script>
  <script>
    var map; 

    require([
      "esri/map", 
      "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, LocateButton)  
    {
      map = new Map("map", {
        center: [-56.049, 38.485],
        zoom: 3,
        basemap: "streets"
      });
            
      geoLocate = new LocateButton({
        map: map
      }, "LocateButton");
      geoLocate.startup();

    });
  </script>

  </head>  
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map">
    <div id="LocateButton"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

So yeah, I don't know where to search really, if you can direct me or help me out figuring how am I supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some information data about the location detected by using the 'locate' event.
In there you will find the coordinates of the location and much more. I personally tried to convert coordinates to address but there is not much ArcGIS support right now. If you find a way through Google's API maybe you will be able to finally get the city through the coordinates ArcGIS gives you.

```js
geoLocate.on('locate', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You will find a working example of the event I mentioned above [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-cannon-od3zs?file=/index.html).

Comment: hey, thanks for your comment,
am i seeing the data through source? what kind of data am i suppose to get in the log? and how can i use it in order to display amount of sick people in the area? 
sorry if u explained and i didnt understand.

Comment: You suppose to see some data given by ArcGIS API. For example coordinates of user's location. The thing is you need the exact address in order to display "the amount of sick people". This is where gave a try but I failed. You are supposed to get the latitude, longitude of user's location and then somehow convert it to adress so you can get the city.

Comment: hey sorry for delay,
may i ask how can i use this coords inside the locate data?
i want to put it inside lets say:
let Lat: data coords
let Long: data coords
how can i reach that? taking the coords information into a variable or something

Comment: @idanhalf ````let Lat = data.position.coords.latitude;````

Comment: okay ill try that, may i ask where can i find more information about the geolocate.on and stuff? so i can read myself and not bother u